# BeautifulSoup getting href of a list with ++ 10k records

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup getting href of a list with ++ records

I have the following soup:

```
<a href="some_url">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
```

From this I want to extract the href, "some_url"

and the whole list of the pages that are listed on this page: https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/laa.html

**note**: there are a whole lot of links to sub-pages: which i need to parse.
at the moment: I'm using the standard documentation over at Crummy, but I'm looking for something a little more organized.

what i have is:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/laa.html">next</a>
<span class="class"><a href="another_url">later</a></span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print ("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

The expected output should be:

```
Found the URL: some_url
Found the URL: another_url
```

and if you look at the page mentioned above i want all tags with an href,  so i thought that i have to omit the name parameter:

```
href_tags = soup.find_all(href=True)
```

any ideas how to get the first steps done..!?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What links do you want to get? Or do you want to only navigate to all subpages?

Comment: good thoughts - guess that he wants to gather the data that are in the sub-pages.  I.e. the datasets of the dioceses that are listed on the page.

Comment: Your import should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: yes - this would be helpful - since we nowadays use bs4

Comment: @aneroid - your idea gives back the following:  `Found the URL: https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/laa.html
Found the URL: another_url` 
note: there are more than 70 urls and towns listed on each of the page of the alphabet - i guess that we need to refine the method a bit - in order to get more out of it.

Comment: @aneroid and @Andrej Kesely: note: we ve got a structured view - see the overview: `https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/qview.html` this could be helpful
for all futher investigations and works: btw: what about iterating over the set of urls:  `A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |`
we could do this with a certain concept of bs4 - and then fetching the data out of the subpages - and finally  - subsequently - store it in a df - with panda, What do you think about it!?- this could be a interesting way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example will grab all URLs of dioceses, get some info about each of them and creates final dataframe. To speed-up the process `multiprocessing.Pool` is used:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool


def get_dioceses_urls(section_url):
    dioceses_urls = set()

    while True:
        print(section_url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(section_url, headers=headers).content, "lxml"
        )
        for a in soup.select('ul a[href^="d"]'):
            dioceses_urls.add(
                "https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/" + a["href"]
            )

        # is there Next Page button?
        next_page = soup.select_one('a:has(img[alt="[Next Page]"])')
        if next_page:
            section_url = (
                "https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/"
                + next_page["href"]
            )
        else:
            break

    return dioceses_urls


def get_diocese_info(url):
    print(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html5lib")

    data = {
        "Title 1": soup.h1.get_text(strip=True),
        "Title 2": soup.h2.get_text(strip=True),
        "Title 3": soup.h3.get_text(strip=True) if soup.h3 else "-",
        "URL": url,
    }

    li = soup.find(
        lambda tag: tag.name == "li"
        and "type of jurisdiction:" in tag.text.lower()
        and tag.find() is None
    )
    if li:
        for l in li.find_previous("ul").find_all("li"):
            t = l.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            if ":" in t:
                k, v = t.split(":", maxsplit=1)
                data[k.strip()] = v.strip()

    # get other info about the diocese
    # ...

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
    }

    # get main sections:
    url = "https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/laa.html"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )

    main_sections = [url]
    for a in soup.select("a[target='_parent']"):
        main_sections.append(
            "https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/" + a["href"]
        )

    all_data, dioceses_urls = [], set()
    with Pool() as pool:
        # get all dioceses urls:
        for urls in pool.imap_unordered(get_dioceses_urls, main_sections):
            dioceses_urls.update(urls)

        # get info about all dioceses:
        for info in pool.imap_unordered(get_diocese_info, dioceses_urls):
            all_data.append(info)

    # create dataframe from the info about dioceses
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).sort_values("Title 1")

    # save it to csv file
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
    print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 | URL | Type of Jurisdiction | Established | Description | Elevated | Metropolitan | Rite | Country | Mailing Address | Italian Title | Erected | Square Kilometers | Telephone | Official Web Site | Fax | Province | Conference Region | Catholic Directory Abbreviation | Name Changed | State | Region | Web Site | United | Split | Restored | Cardinal’s Blog | The Pilot | Territory Added | Offcial Web Site | Cathedral | See Transferred | Diocesan Newspaper | Catholic Communications Network | Square Miles | Vatican Web Site | Official Web Site (old) | Santuario della Santa Casa di Loreto | Blog | Official Blog | Cathedral Web Site | Archdiocesan Newspaper | Catholic News Service | Basilica de Esquipulas | Parish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1934 | Abaradira | (Titular See) | Abaradirensis | https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/d2a01.html | Titular See | 1933 | pr. Bizacena | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 632 | Abari | (Titular See) | Abaritanus | https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/d2a02.html | Titular See | 1933 | pr. Bizacena | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 5441 | Abbir Germaniciana | (Titular See) | Abbiritanus Germanicianorum | https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/d2a03.html | Titular See | 1933 | pr. Proconsolare; m. Cartagine | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 4388 | Abbir Maius | (Titular See) | Abbiritanus | https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/d2a04.html | Titular See | nan | pr. Proconsolare; m. Cartagine | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | Abbir Maggiore | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 6065 | Abdera | (Titular See) | Abderitanus | https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/d4a57.html | Titular See | nan | pr. Rhodope in Tracia; m. Traianopoli | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: hi dear Andrej - this is so awesome. Just another great example that shows your your awesome python-insights. Thanks for posting this great ideas and interesting thoughts - this is very helpful. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

this will be my first answer on Stackoverflow. I hope I can help :)

I want to show you a simple method to get the urls on the page you specified!

In order to fulfill your need, we will use the module called scrapeasy. It would be appropriate to say that it is a simple webscraping library for Python. Likewise, although it is very simple to use, it is very functional.

Let's go to our example:

```
from scrapeasy import Website, Page

web = Website("https://targetsite.com")
links = web.getSubpagesLinks()

for i in range(0, len(links)):
    print(links[i])
```

There is a very simple usage method like this for Scrapeasy.
I hope you review the documentation and discover other usable methods.

Comment: hi there Alesko, This is a great contribution. Congrats to your very first answer here. 

Looks awesome: It looks very good and seems to be apropiate. BTW: what if someone wants to get the subpages - i.e. the pages with the dioceses mentioned - and want to scrape those pages. Is this possible with the method that you have mentioned. This would be awesome. - If we do not need bs4, request and Pandas here - (btw. if we can do this with pandas and df - this would be a intersting approach too - since pandas is pretty puwerful 
look forward to hear from you - regards

Comment: Hello dear Alesko, The above mentioned example grabs all URLs of dioceses, to speed-up the process multiprocessing.Pool is used:

but wait: how to get this scraper running without the support of the multiprocessing!? i want to run it in Colab - therefore in need to get rid of the multiprocessing-feature. 

how to achieve this..!?

Comment: If you are absolutely sure what kind of url you need, you can filter it like "Python String startswith() Method", Regex or if-else.